# Why running %COMPSEC% in windows Run directly open cmd with administrator priviledges ant not asking or that UAC Yes/No Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, security, administrator, uac

I was doing some malware analysis and stumbled across a code which was executing %COMPSEC% command, and by running it in my own windows run box (as we usually open %temp%, %systemroot%, etc in run) it opened the cmd with administrator privilege without asking Yes/No.
As to me, it is really strange that any application that needs administrator privilege and windows do not ask for UAC (user access control) Yes/No.

Is it intended to be like this or not? and if yes then why, how it is helpful? UAC
It seems to be more of a security issue than a feature to me.

I am running Windows 10  19043

Comment: Do you actually have UAC enabled on this system?

Comment: Since %COMPSEC% isn’t a default variable, and thus does it exist on our systems, you will have to tell us what it is. Difficult to understand how UAC (which isn’t new) is related to a system variable